# How to insert space before capital letter for a String using JAVA?

Tags: java, regex

I have a String `"nameOfThe_String"`. Here 1st letter of the string should be capital. So I have used

`String strJobname="nameOfThe_String";
 strJobname=strJobname.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+strJobname.substring(1);`

Now, I need to insert the space before uppercase letters. So, I used

`strJobname=strJobname.replaceAll("(.)([A-Z])", "$1 $2");`

But here I need the output as `"Name Of The_String"`. After `'_'` I don't need any space even `S` is a capital letter.

How can I do that? Please help me with this.

Answer (score 5):

```
strJobname=strJobname.replaceAll("([^_])([A-Z])", "$1 $2");
```

The ^ character as the first character in square brackets means: Not this character. So, with the first bracket group you say: Any character that is not a _.
However, note that your regex might also insert spaces between consecutive capitals.

Answer (score 2):

With look-arounds you can use:

```
String strJobname="nameOfThe_String";
strJobname = Character.toUpperCase(strJobname.charAt(0)) +
             strJobname.substring(1).replaceAll("(?<!_)(?=[A-Z])", " ");

//=> Name Of The_String
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fY7zmr/1)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different way which may fulfill your requirement.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    input = sc.next();
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(input);
    String find = "([^_])([A-Z])";
    Pattern word = Pattern.compile(find);
    Matcher matcher = word.matcher(text);
    while(matcher.find())
        text = text.insert(matcher.end() - 1, " ");

    System.out.println(text);
}
```